# Memory leak at NSObject allocation

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

HI, I am getting memory leak at NSObject allocation i.e.,

```
ContactDTO* contactDTO = [[ContactDTO alloc] init];
```

Code:

```
+(ContactDTO*) getContactDTOForId:(NSString*) contactId
{
NSString* homeMail =@"";
NSString* workMail=@"";


NSString *lastNameString=@""; 
NSString *firstNameString=@"";

firstNameString = [AddressBookUtil getValueForProperty:kABPersonFirstNameProperty forContact:contactId];
lastNameString = [AddressBookUtil getValueForProperty:kABPersonLastNameProperty forContact:contactId];

ABRecordID contactIntId = [contactId intValue];
ABRecordRef person =   ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, contactIntId);
ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue =(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
for(CFIndex j=0;j<ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMultiValue);j++)
{
    NSString* curentTypeLabel =(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailMultiValue,j);

    if([curentTypeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"]==YES)
    {
        NSString* currentEmail =(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMultiValue,j);
        if([currentEmail isEqualToString:nil]==NO)
        {
            homeMail = [currentEmail copy];
        }
    }
    if([curentTypeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"]==YES)
    {
        NSString* currentEmail =(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMultiValue,j);
        if([currentEmail isEqualToString:nil]==NO)
        {
            workMail = [currentEmail copy];
        }
    }
}

ContactDTO* contactDTO = [[ContactDTO alloc] init];
contactDTO.firstName = firstNameString;
contactDTO.lastName = lastNameString;
contactDTO.contactId = contactId;
contactDTO.homeEmail = homeMail;
contactDTO.workEmail = workMail;

return [contactDTO autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the email addresses from the Address Book you use `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex()` which returns a reference which is owned by you (e.g. must be released using `CFRelease()` by you), as does `[obj copy];`.

I assume you release the `homeMail` and `workMail` in your dealloc method but the copied value from the address book seems leaked in this method.

Comment: I done it as of ur suggestion but still Im getting Memory leak at same place.can u give any other suggestions to get out of this???

Comment: After a second look on your example I see that the `[currentEmail copy];` you're doing is also overhead, just assign them (e.g. `workMail = currentEmail;`). But I agree with Isaac, you should definitively read the Memory Management Programming Guide as such topics are covered there.

Answer (score 1):

You've posted three nearly-identical questions pertaining to memory leaks.  It might be helpful for you to read through [Apple's Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).